# How to create new rows from values inside in a cloumn of pandas dataframe based on delimeter in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like below. I want to split the values inside column zip into row values as shown below. The values can delimited by `_ ,.` by these delimiters. How can this be done in python.

**Input**

```
df.head(5)

    Date    Item_Code   Type    Zip
    1/1/2020    A   Long    07_08_09
    12/4/2020   B   Small   AB_CD_EF_GF
    13/4/2020   A   Long    08_14
    1/5/2020    A   Long    
    21/5/2020   B   Small   09,07,16
    22/5/2020   B   Small   AB,07
```

**Expected Output**

```
Date    Item_Code   Type    Zip
1/1/2020    A      Long    07
1/1/2020    A      Long    08
1/1/2020    A      Long    09
12/4/2020   B      Small   AB
12/4/2020   B      Small   CD
12/4/2020   B      Small   EF
12/4/2020   B      Small   GF
13/4/2020   A      Long    08
13/4/2020   A      Long    14
1/5/2020    A      Long 
21/5/2020   B      Small   09
21/5/2020   B      Small   07
21/5/2020   B      Small   16
22/5/2020   B      Small   AB
22/5/2020   B      Small   07
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) witg regexes first, assign back by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and then use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), also ic created default unique index in last step:

```
df1 = (df.assign(Zip = df['Zip'].str.split('[_ ,\.]'))
         .explode('Zip')
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
         Date Item_Code   Type  Zip
0    1/1/2020         A   Long   07
1    1/1/2020         A   Long   08
2    1/1/2020         A   Long   09
3   12/4/2020         B  Small   AB
4   12/4/2020         B  Small   CD
5   12/4/2020         B  Small   EF
6   12/4/2020         B  Small   GF
7   13/4/2020         A   Long   08
8   13/4/2020         A   Long   14
9    1/5/2020         A   Long  NaN
10  21/5/2020         B  Small   09
11  21/5/2020         B  Small   07
12  21/5/2020         B  Small   16
13  22/5/2020         B  Small   AB
14  22/5/2020         B  Small   07
```

Comment: I knew you'd be the first to answer!  Learning something new every day, thanks.

Comment: @jezrael, getting an error `DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'`

Comment: @pankaj - Is possible upgrade pandas?

Comment: @jezrael, Let me try, which version

Comment: @pankaj - It working from 0.25+, so if use last one 1.0.3 it working nice

Comment: @jezrael,I upgraded to '1.0.3`. Still its failing due to same error.

Comment: @pankaj - Is possible restart IDE?